# Ignore VB.net 2012 events at statup

Tags: vb.net

So here is the deal.

I'm using a VB.net 2012.

I have textBox with `TextChanged` event. And it has some value in it. 
But before I use this event I must load some of the functions. 
So when I load the form I got error cuz the code reads this event and the functions aren't loaded. 
What I want to do is to ignore those events when I start the form for the first time :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does “load some of the functions” mean, and shouldn’t you be doing that in `New()`?

Comment: I am populating some lists in those functions.
And when I type something in the textbox I use those lists.
But If those functions are not loaded I will get an error when I try to write something in that textbox cuz the lists are not set. Got it ? :/

Comment: What do the functions do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup a Flag and check it in the TextChanged() event.  Toggle the flag in the Shown() event:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Loading As Boolean = True

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.Text = "Hello from the Load() event!"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        Loading = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        If Not Loading Then
            Debug.Print("TextChanged")
            ' ... your code in here ...
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: It works this way, but I have to check at every textbox for Loading.. I know there is another way...I read it somewhere. I appreciate this. Thank you